# Interperting $\bigcap_{J\subset I\\J<\infty}\sigma(\bigcup_{j\in I\setminus J}A_j)$ tail sigma-algebra

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

> Tail $\sigma$-algebra. Let $I$ be a countably infinite index set and let $(\mathscr{A}_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ be a family of $\sigma$-algebras. Then:
>
> $T((\mathscr{A}_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}})=\bigcap_{J\subset I\\J<\infty}\sigma(\bigcup_{j\in I\setminus J}A_j)$
> is called the tail $\sigma$-algebra of $(\mathscr{A}_i))_{i\in\mathbb{N}}.$

I have been stuck trying to make sense of this definition. As I understand there is the generation of a sigma-algebra of the unions of of elements that are I elements. But then there is the intersection of J elementes that are in I. How can those elemnts be in I if they were excluded in the union?

**Question**:

How should I interpret the definition?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example, which illustrates the definition. Consider a family of random variables $\{X_i:i\in I\}$. For $J\subset I$, let $\mathcal{B}_J:=\sigma(\{X_i:i\notin J\})$, which is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by all $X_i$'s whose indices are not in $J$. Then
$$
\mathcal{T}:=\bigcap_{J\subset I,|J|<\infty}\mathcal{B}_J
$$
is the tail $\sigma$-algebra. An event belongs to $\mathcal{T}$ if it is not influenced by any finite collection of $X_i$'s. When $I= \mathbb{N}$, standard examples are:
$$
\left\{\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i\le n} X_i\text{ exists}\right\}\in\mathcal{T}
$$
and
$$
\left\{\limsup_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i\le n} X_i>0\right\}\notin\mathcal{T}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

It is the sigma algebra of sets with the property that the set belongs to sigma algebra generated by $\mathcal A_i$'s even if you remove  a finite number of $\mathcal A_i$'s. For example if we start with  a sequence $\mathcal A_i, i=1,2,\cdots$ then the set of points which belong to infinitely many of these sigma algebras belongs to the tail sigma algebra but set of points which belong to all of these sigma algebras need not belong to the tail sigma algebra.